# Scala Slick How to insert rows with a previously returned autoincremental ID

Tags: scala, orm, slick

Here is the thing.

I'm using Slick 3.1.0 and basically I got two models and one has a FK constraint on the other. Let's say:

```
case class FooRecord(id: Option[Int], name: String, oneValue: Int)

class FooTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[FooRecord](tag, "FOO"){
  def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("NAME")
  def oneValue = column[Int]("ONEVALUE")
}
val fooTable =  TableQuery[FooTable]
```

and

```
case class BarRecord(id: Option[Int], name: String, foo_id: Int)

class BarTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[BarRecord](tag, "BAR"){
  def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("NAME")
  def fooId = column[Int]("FOO_ID")
  def foo = foreignKey("foo_fk", fooId, fooTable)(_.id)
}
```

These are intended to store one Foo, and several Bars, where for one Bar there is only One Foo.
I've been trying to figure how to perform the complete set of insert statements on a single transaction. ie.

```
DBIO.seq( 
 (fooTable returning fooTable.map(_id)) += Foo(None, "MyName", 42),
 (barTable returning batTable.map(_id)) += Bar(None, "MyBarname", FOO_KEY)
)
```

but the thing is I could not find the way to get Foo ID to be used as a FOO_KEY on Bar instance field.
Of course I can perform the DBAction twice but it's pretty awful in my opinion.
Any thought?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is just to sequence your DBIO transactions and pass the result of the first into the second:

```
val insertDBIO = for {
  fooId <- (fooTable returning fooTable.map(_id)) += Foo(None, "MyName", 42)
  barId <- (barTable returning batTable.map(_id)) += Bar(None, "MyBarname", fooId)
} yield (fooId, barId)

db.run(insertDBIO.transactionally)
```

The `transactionally` call will ensure that both are run on the same connection.

Comment: At last I use a pretty similar approach, but didnt know about transactionally. Awesome. works smoothly!